# Create database migration from model in Laravel 5

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, model, migration

In Laravel 5, how can I create a database migration based on my existing model.

I believe this is possible in frameworks like ASP.NET (https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/tutorials/first-mvc-app/adding-model.html).

How can I do it in Laravel 5?

Comment: Backwards thinking. Structure drives data interaction, not the opposite. Just another personal problem I have with enterprise development. It tries to be so many things to so many people without any one clear path or direction.

Comment: I have not seen that with Eloquent, but with Doctrine (you can use Doctrine in Laravel, too).

Comment: @herrjeh42 Which lib specifically. Can you send a link? They seem to do a LOT

Comment: https://www.sitepoint.com/laravel-doctrine-best-of-both-worlds/